# Php artisan migrate in laravel 5.8 with Ubuntu 18

Tags: laravel-5.8

After my laravel's project installation and configure .env, I have this as an error message when i try to execute `php artisan migrate`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XGWfk.jpg)

Comment: It can't be read on the image you posted. Can you copy the issue here? (I suspect you don't have mysql installed)

Comment: Are you using mysql? If so have you installed the php-mysql driver?

Answer (score 0):

Hey find this file `AppServiceProvider.php` and put this below code

```
public function boot() {
 \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema::defaultStringLength(191);

}
```